# How serious is the uncommitted movement against Biden's Gaza policy?

Tags: united-states, democracy, 2023-israel-hamas-war

[How the uncommitted vote against Biden’s Gaza policy is going 'national'](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/3/18/how-the-uncommitted-vote-against-bidens-gaza-policy-is-going-national)

> Washington, DC – The organisers of Listen to Michigan — an effort to protest Joe Biden’s policy towards Israel’s war in Gaza — have a message for the United States president: The conflict is not a “niche” issue for only some segments of the political left.
>
> Listen to Michigan emerged earlier this year as a grassroots movement focused on the state’s primary. It called on voters to cast “uncommitted votes” instead of backing Biden’s reelection effort, in an attempt to signal displeasure over the president’s stance on the war.
>
> But that movement has kicked off a domino effect in other key states, with similar “protest votes” emerging. On Monday, Listen to Michigan unveiled plans to take its campaign to the national stage.
>
> “Since we launched our campaign in Michigan, critics have gone out of their way to minimise the momentum of ‘uncommitted’ and Listen to Michigan and what this movement has gained as a niche issue of the left,” Layla Elabed, a key Michigan organiser, said during a news conference on Monday.
>
> “Today, we launched our national movement to let you all know uncommitted voters aren’t going anywhere, and we aren’t backing down until we achieve a permanent ceasefire.”

Okay, but if enough people don't vote for Biden, the obvious result would be Trump winning the election. Since Trump is [even more pro-Israel](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/donald-trump/trump-israel-gaza-finish-problem-rcna141905) than Biden, movements like Listen to Michigan sound self-defeating.

I'm wondering how serious these movements are about not voting for Biden, and/or if any of them have addressed the (obvious?) counterargument against doing that above.

Comment: I was under the impression that "uncommitted" was more of a primary thing. It had no effect on the outcome there. But aside from that: In an entrenched two-party system like ours, *threatening to stay home* is pretty much the only move available to the smaller side in an intra-party conflict. I would guess they're not serious though. It takes both a lot of discipline, and tolerance for being shouted down by the party mainstream who seem to just want to blame Netanyahu, make empty statements about two-state solution, but avoid substantive change to US support for Israel.

Comment: I feel like this question is subjective. How does one define "serious"? If you asked someone who didn't vote for Biden in the primary because of X issue, someone who didn't vote for Biden in the general election because of X issue, and someone who voted for Biden in both despite X issue, they would *all* probably describe their position as "serious," and might well claim that their stance is the *only* one that people who feel seriously about the issue should take (X issue, because this is true going beyond people whose votes are primarily driven by the war in the Gaza Strip).

Comment: @Obie2.0 for the purposes of this question, define 'serious' as "I'm not voting for Biden in the election".

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/85991/us-electoral-opposition-to-biden-support-of-israel-have-any-pro-palestine-pol/

Comment: @Allure Please clarify that in the question. "Uncommitted" is a primary elections thing and doesn't affect the fact that Biden will be the DNC candidate.